# Pandas Merge On Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to merge the below two dataframes to yield the below result.

Table_1

| foo1 | foo2 | date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 4/20 | 6 | NaN |
| a | b | 4/19 | NaN | 2 |
| a | b | 4/18 | NaN | 1 |

Table_2

| foo1 | foo2 | date | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 4/20 | 2 |
| a | b | 4/10 | 1 |

I'm able to yield the below result using this merge.

table_1 = table_1.merge(table_2,how='outer',left_on=['foo1','foo2','date'],right_on=['foo1','foo2','date'])

Resulting table

| foo1 | foo2 | date | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 4/20 | 6 | NaN | NaN |
| a | b | 4/19 | NaN | 2 | NaN |
| a | b | 4/18 | NaN | 1 | NaN |
| a | b | 4/20 | NaN | NaN | 2 |
| a | b | 4/10 | NaN | NaN | 1 |

I need any of the rows that match with those three columns to merge together.

Ideal result

| foo1 | foo2 | date | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 4/20 | 6 | NaN | 2 |
| a | b | 4/19 | NaN | 2 | NaN |
| a | b | 4/18 | NaN | 1 | NaN |
| a | b | 4/10 | NaN | NaN | 1 |

How should I merge these two dataframes?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions read please

Comment: You've made a good start on this -- the initial pair of data frames are no longer needed. Show us your .groupby() code, please, along with its output. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby Feel free to do it as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: your code as written should work. Are you sure your data is clean? Maybe there's whitespace that's causing some mismatch

Answer (score 1):

you could do this:

```
pd.merge(Table_1, Table_2, how="outer", on=['foo1','foo2','date'])
```